# Stuck on Java program that tallies grades and shows results

Tags: java, find, average

I'm taking a beginners course in Java and they asked us to:

- Write a program to tally the number of A's, B's, C's, D's and F's based upon a list of scores entered by a user.
- After all the scores are entered, the program must display a
  horizontal bar graph of the number tallied for each grade like that shown in the Operation section.
- The tally graph must display a single '*' for each unit tallied.
- When a user enters a -1, the program must display the final graph and
  exit.
- The output of your program must display prompts and a tally graph
  like that shown in the Operation section above.
- You may assume that a user will enter numbers only.

Operation:

The program starts and prompts you to either enter a test score or end
the program by entering a -1. Like the following:

```
Number of A's: 0
Number of B's: 0
Number of C's: 0
Number of D's: 0
Number of F's: 0
Enter a score (%) or -1 to end: 90
```

As you enter each score, the application decides whether the score is
an A, B, C, D or F and adds one to the letter-grade tally. Like the
following:

```
Number of A's: 1
Number of B's: 0
Number of C's: 0
Number of D's: 0
Number of F's: 0
Enter a score (%) or -1 to end: 95
```

Each time you enter a score, the program updates the tally. Like the following:

```
Number of A's: 2
Number of B's: 0
Number of C's: 0
Number of D's: 0
Number of F's: 0
Enter a score (%) or -1 to end: -1
```

When you are done entering scores, the program displays a horizontal
bar graph of the tally for A's, B's, C's, D's and F's. Like the
following:

```
A's: **
B's:
C's:
D's:
F's:
```

Specifications:

Numerical Grade                             Letter Grade

greater than or equal to 90                      A

less than 90 but greater than or equal to 80     B

less than 80 but greater than or equal to 70     C

less than 70 but greater than or equal to 60     D

less than 60                                     F

When the program ends, display the number of scores, average score, and best score.

Example:

Number of scores:  2

Average score: 92.5

Best score: 95.0

We have also been instructed to code in at least two methods : one that has a void and one that returns something.

So far I have only been able to tally up the scores entered, but I don't seem to be able to wrap my head around *recording all the inputs* and *calculating the average* and *picking out the best score*

This is what I have so far :

```
    import java.util.*;


    public class ScoreTally {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


            int aCount = 0;
            int bCount = 0;
            int cCount = 0;
            int dCount = 0;
            int fCount = 0;
            int scoreCount = -1;

            double score = 0;



            while (score != -1) {
                if (score >= 90)
                    aCount++;

                else if ((score < 90) && (score >= 80))
                    bCount++;

                 else if ((score < 80) && (score >= 70))
                    cCount++;

                else if ((score < 70) && (score >= 60))
                    dCount++;

                else if ((score < 60) && (score > 0))
                    fCount++;

                System.out.println("Number of A's: " + aCount);
                System.out.println("Number of B's: " + bCount);
                System.out.println("Number of C's: " + cCount);
                System.out.println("Number of D's: " + dCount);
                System.out.println("Number of F's: " + fCount);
                System.out.print("Enter a score (%) or -1 to end: ");
                score = input.nextDouble();

                scoreCount++;

            }

            if (score == -1)
                System.out.println("Number of scores: " + scoreCount);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Step one: java is an object oriented language.  don't do everything in the main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function to return the greatest number to get your best score.
And another function to print the final graph.
That should take care of the two function requirement.
Also, make the loop an exit-controlled one, as it has to run atleast once.

As a coding practice, you should not be using star imports(import java.util.*) instead use only what you need.

Also, good work on setting the scoreCount to -1 in the beginning.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScoreTally {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    int aCount = 0;
    int bCount = 0;
    int cCount = 0;
    int dCount = 0;
    int fCount = 0;
    int scoreCount = -1;

    double score;
    double totalScore = 0;
    double bestScore = -1;


    do {
        System.out.println("Number of A's: " + aCount);
        System.out.println("Number of B's: " + bCount);
        System.out.println("Number of C's: " + cCount);
        System.out.println("Number of D's: " + dCount);
        System.out.println("Number of F's: " + fCount);
        System.out.print("Enter a score (%) or -1 to end: ");
        score = input.nextDouble();
        if (score >= 90) {
            aCount++;
        } else if ((score < 90) && (score >= 80)) {
            bCount++;
        } else if ((score < 80) && (score >= 70)) {
            cCount++;
        } else if ((score < 70) && (score >= 60)) {
            dCount++;
        } else if ((score < 60) && (score > 0)) {
            fCount++;
        }
        scoreCount++;
        totalScore = totalScore + score;
        bestScore = greaterNumber(bestScore, score);


    } while (score != -1);

    printGraph('A', aCount);
    printGraph('B', bCount);
    printGraph('C', cCount);
    printGraph('D', dCount);
    printGraph('F', fCount);
    System.out.println("Number of scores: " + scoreCount);
    System.out.println("Average scores: " + totalScore / scoreCount);
    System.out.println("Best scores: " + bestScore);

}

public static void printGraph(char grade, int count) {
    System.out.print("Number of " + grade + "'s: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static double greaterNumber(double firstNum, double secondNum) {
    if (firstNum >= secondNum) {
        return firstNum;
    } else {
        return secondNum;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much. This corresponds perfectly with the requirements and gives me some awesome examples on how to code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you already have the code to tally the results.

```
        int aCount = 0;
        int bCount = 0;
        int cCount = 0;
        int dCount = 0;
        int fCount = 0;
        int scoreCount = -1;
```

What you need is another field that will hold the total score i.e.

```
int totalScore = 0;
```

You need to prompt for the first score before you enter the while loop otherwise it won't run properly the first iteration. At the end (or the beginning) you need to update `totalScore` with whatever was the input for that round, and not update it if the input was -1.

The average score will just be the `totalScore/scoreCount` you should compute that after you finish the while loop.

For the best score you can have another field for `int = maxScore`

you can update it every iteration of the loop with

`maxScore = Math.max(maxScore, score);`

Math.max returns the maximum of the two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather simple. Declare 2 variables, one for having avgScore, one for in beginning of your program.

```
double bestScore = 0.0;
double avgScore = 0.0;
double totalScore = 0.0;
while (score != -1) {
                totalScore = totalScore + score;
                if(score > bestScore)
                    bestScore = score;  
                if (score >= 90)
                    aCount++;

                else if ((score < 90) && (score >= 80))
                    bCount++;

                 else if ((score < 80) && (score >= 70))
                    cCount++;

                else if ((score < 70) && (score >= 60))
                    dCount++;

                else if ((score < 60) && (score > 0))
                    fCount++;

                System.out.println("Number of A's: " + aCount);
                System.out.println("Number of B's: " + bCount);
                System.out.println("Number of C's: " + cCount);
                System.out.println("Number of D's: " + dCount);
                System.out.println("Number of F's: " + fCount);
                System.out.print("Enter a score (%) or -1 to end: ");
                score = input.nextDouble();

                scoreCount++;

            }

            if (score == -1){
                System.out.println("Number of scores: " + scoreCount);
                avgScore = totalScore/scoreCount;
                System.out.println("Best Score: " + bestScore);
                System.out.println("Avg Score: " + avgScore);
            }
```

Also for displaying the chart you can use your final tallies.